# Datetime picker - Range of time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I have this model:

```
create_table "schedules", force: :cascade do |t|
t.datetime "start_time"
t.datetime "end_time"
t.integer  "property_id"
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
t.string   "phone"
t.string   "email"
t.index ["property_id"], name: "index_schedules_on_property_id"
```

end

And I wanna separate my start_time in date and time.
With the time I want to select a range between 08:00 .. 18:00.

eg: a select box with [08:00, 09:00, 10:00]

Because when I save the date and time, it will not be allowed to choose again the same time to that day.

Did I make myself clear?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @Jordan how can I separate my start_time in date and time. And with the time I want to select a range between 08:00 .. 18:00?

Comment: Can you provide and example of the form you are using? We can't help you if we can't see the code you are attempting to make work.